# Recover my funds from Safe without threshold

Tags: gnosis-safe

I pooled my funds with a business partner in several Safe vaults. He recently added another owner and changed the threshold to 2, locking me out. He won't let me access any of my funds, and he sent a substantial amount from the Eth safe today to his personal account.
I had 330k I added to the Safe that I don't have access to now.
I need help recovering my funds back to one of my personal wallets.

Answer (score 1):

> I pooled my funds with a business partner in several Safe vaults. He recently added another owner and changed the threshold to 2, locking me out. He won't let me access any of my funds, and he sent a substantial amount from the Eth safe today to his personal account.

This is a social and legal problem, and unfortunately no one on this site can help you. File a fraud report against your business part to a local police.